# EVENT mysql on PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

With this PHP CODE i can insert into DB (i changed name of $) results of list people eat @my hotel every day. This code is ok for PHP, already works.

```php
$dataogg=ucwords(strftime("%a %d %B %Y"));

if ($_GET["reportMen"]){
$dba="dbxxxxxx";
@mysql_connect("localhost","exexex","xexexe") or die("Demo 1 is not available, please try again later");
@mysql_select_db($dbxxxxxx);

$contGGtot = "SELECT COUNT(GGLIMIT) AS total FROM tab1 WHERE  GGLIMIT=1"; 
$resultGG = mysql_query($contGGtot); 
$valuesGG = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultGG); 
$num_rowsGG = $valuesGG['total'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO  `dbxxxxxx`.`report` (`ID` ,`DATA` ,`TOTALE`) VALUES (NULL ,  '".$dataogg."',  '".$num_rowsGG."');";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Now, i need to insert this code inside EVENT on my mysql in phpmyadmin.
Basically i create a data, daily select total count, insert into DB.
I think i can't put php $ on EVENT. Please help me to simplify these sql query in correct language

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use php variables in a mysql stored code. The good news is: you do not have to.

1. You do not have to connect to a mysql instance from an event, since the event runs within mysql.
2. Instead of using a select and then an insert just use insert with a select in one of the variables and use [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format the time.

`insert into dbxxxxxx.report (ID ,DATA ,TOTALE) VALUES (NULL ,date_format(now(),'%a %d %M %Y') ,(SELECT COUNT(GGLIMIT) FROM tab1 WHERE  GGLIMIT=1))`